# Input 0 of layer "fc-3" is incompatible with the layer

Tags: deep-learning

I have tried to add additional layer to the Keras model I'm getting error

[image]

[image]

> value error ValueError: in user code:    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 878, in train_function  *        return step_function(self,
> iterator)    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 867, in step_function  **        outputs =
> model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 860, in run_step  **        outputs = model.train_step(data)
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 808, in train_step        y_pred = self(x, training=True)    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py",
> line 67, in error_handler        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb)
> from None    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer
> "side_ncf" (type SideNCF).        in user code:            File
> "", line 42, in call  *            fc_4
> = self.dense3(fc_3)        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py",
> line 67, in error_handler  **            raise
> e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None        File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py",
> line 248, in assert_input_compatibility            f'Input
> {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '            ValueError:
> Input 0 of layer "fc-3" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis
> -1of input shape to have value 50, but received input with shape (None, 25)            Call arguments received:      •
> inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 4), dtype=float32)',
> 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 3), dtype=int64)') site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: It will be helpful to solve the problem if the part of the code where you pass input data into the model could also be provided, Thanks!

Comment: it seems like the layer fc-2 is outputting a vector with axis -1 of size 50, so when it is passed as input to the next layer i.e. fc-3, it errors out as the required input shape is 25. Try changing the line - `self.dense3 = layers.Dense(25, name = 'fc-3', activation = 'relu')` to `self.dense3 = layers.Dense(50, name = 'fc-3', activation = 'relu')`

Comment: Hi thanks for solving the error can you tell me like
self.dense2 = layers.Dense(50, name = 'fc-3', activation = 'relu') 
self.dense3 = layers.Dense(50, name = 'fc-3', activation = 'relu')
consecutive layers can they have same number of inputs in this case 50 for dense layer two and three also what would be another combination starting from dense layer1 self.dense1 like 100,50,40 like that can you suggest any combination

Comment: They have used validation_split=.2 and test_size=0.33 can you tell me what is the difference and where they are called in the code

Comment: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [33276, 1663800]

Im getting error when i change to self.dense3 = layers.Dense(25, name = 'fc-3', activation = 'relu') to self.dense3 = layers.Dense(50, name = 'fc-3', activation = 'relu') can you tell me how to change the framework

Comment: for your first question, the answer is you can figure out what the input of the next layer should be by getting/printing the output_shape of the prevous layer.

Comment: for the other issues you have, i would suggest you create a new thread/question that way anyone in the future would also be able to find it, just link the question here I will try my best to help in all possible ways <3

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE]" and all their linked pages along with "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
and "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)", "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" and
"[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)". They'll help us help you.